# why my PyOpenGL shader code keeps making error?

Tags: opengl, shader, pyopengl

I made shader in PyOpenGL but it keeps making error

```
vertex_src = """
# version 330 
in vec3 a_position; 

void main()
{
    gl_Position  = vec4(a_position, 1.0);
}
"""

fragment_src = """
# version 330 

out vec4 out_color;

void main()
{
    out_color  = vec4(1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0); 
}
"""
```

```
shader = compileProgram(compileShader(vertex_src, GL_VERTEX_SHADER), compileShader(fragment_src, GL_FRAGMENT_SHADER))
glUseProgram(shader)
```

```
RuntimeError: ('Shader compile failure (0): b"ERROR: 0:3: Invalid storage qualifiers \'in\' in global variable context\\nERROR: 0:7: Use of undeclared identifier \'a_position\'\\n"', [b'\n\nin vec3 a_position; \n\nvoid main()\n{\n    gl_Position  = vec4(a_position, 1.0);\n}\n'], GL_VERTEX_SHADER)
```

I checked semicolon, vectors, etc but everything is fine. please help me fix the problem

Comment: I tried almost all the version from 100 to 460 but all of them give me same error please help

Comment: Which OpenGL version are you using? I'd guess you're stuck at a legacy GL 2.1 context.

Answer (score 0):

if u are running a version < 330 the shaders work a little bit different:

use

```
gl_version = float(gl.glGetString(gl.GL_VERSION)[:3])
```

to find out your version of opengl, and than search for the GLSL-version it supports

for your shaders that would mean:

**vertex:**

```
#version 120

attribute vec3 position;

void main()
{
  gl_Position = vec4(position, 1.0);
}
```

**fragment:**

```
#version 120


void main()
{

  gl_FragColor = vec4(1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0);
}
```